# Java Virtual Machine Internals

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, internals

Can u suggest some articles or books about JVM internals: how it allocates memory, handles object inheritance, garbage collection, how it executes byte code and so on.

Comment: This helps: http://bayanbox.ir/view/7483327857412930783/java-execution-process.png

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at "[Inside the JVM](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/index.html)". Unfortunately I'm not aware of the existence of any new books on the subject.

Comment: +1. This is a good book. The JVM specification, on the other hand, is just that - a specification, and not very readable unless you're writing your own VM.

Answer (score 2):

Cliff Click did a great Google talk earlier this year on the things that a JVM does. It's certainly not everything that you'd need, but is a really great starting point:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uL2D3qzHtqY&feature=player_embedded

I'd also add that if you don't already understand bytecode, then that's going to be pretty useful:

http://arhipov.blogspot.com/2011/01/java-bytecode-fundamentals.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at "The Java Virtual Machine Specification": http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/

Answer (score 0):

Also helpfull: The <s>[Hotspot wiki](http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Home)</s> [OpenJDK wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Main)

Comment: The link is dead.